# Set title of tab bars programmatically

Tags: iphone, tabs

I have five tabs in my main window, but I haven't created it programmatically.

What should I do to create the title through code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hey do you want to set the title of the tab bar button or the viewcontroller that is associated with the tab?

If you are looking for the first thing then do it like:

```
UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[[tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:yourIndex];
[tabItem setTitle:@"theTitle"];
```

otherwise `mihirpmehta` is correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i was trying to set title of tab bar button.

wat i just did is just provided 

self.title = @"Title";
at viewdidload..
and tab bar's as well as viewcontroller's title has beeen set to "title."

is this proper?????

Answer (score 5):

OR

```
[(UIViewController *)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:@"Title1"];
```

Comment: it is right answer... don't down vote it just because you can't understand it or it doesn't match with your opinion..

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize and use a UITabBarItem object using the following functions:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title image:(UIImage *)image tag:(NSInteger)tag; // selected image autogenerated
- (id)initWithTabBarSystemItem:(UITabBarSystemItem)systemItem tag:(NSInteger)tag
```

And then you can call this method on your tabBar object:

```
- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

where items id the array to which you have added all your tabBarItem objects. There is also a badgeValue property for UITabBarItem if you need to use.

Comment: thanks man,

i only need to provide name  programmatially, rest will be the same...
any other way to provide title manually???

Answer (score 0):

If your `UIViewController` is wrapped in a `UINavigationController`, do the following:

```
self.navigationController?.tabBarItem.title = "Awesome Title"
```